# A possible characterization of regular cardinals?

Tags: set-theory

For a cardinal $\kappa$ by $[\kappa]^{<\kappa}$ we denote the family of all subsets of cardinality $<\kappa$ in $\kappa$.

> **Question.** Assume that for an infinite cardinal $\kappa$ there exists a family $\mathcal B\subset[\kappa]^{<\kappa}$ of cardinality $|\mathcal B|=\kappa$ such that for any $A\in[\kappa]^{<\kappa}$ the set $\{B\in\mathcal B:A\not\subset B\}$ has cardinality $<\kappa$. Is $\kappa$ a regular cardinal?

Comment: I don't know about characterization, I think that under MA or something we can get this to fail with $\kappa=\aleph_1$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It seems that I have found an affirmative answer to this question. But the proof of a bit lengthy. I needed this property for the proof of normality of balleans on groups and it turns out that I can prove this property using the technique of balleans. But maybe there are direct proofs.

Comment: I can believe that. I just think that this is not a characterization per se, just a condition that implies regularity.

Comment: @AsafKaragila No, it is a characterization: if a cardinal $\kappa$ is regular then the family $\mathcal B$ consiting of the initial intervals of $\kappa$ has the required property.

Comment: Oh. You're absolutely right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The assumption implies that $\mathcal{B}$ is cofinal in the poset $[\kappa]^{<\kappa}$, and hence that this poset has cofinality $\le\kappa$. This implies that $\kappa$ is regular, [by this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/313447/14094).